# Is there a way to show previous messages in screen?

Tags: terminal, gnu-screen

When I use `screen` I can only see the current data on the terminal (commands, messages, etc.).

Is there a way, apart from printing anything I want to a file, to see the previous messages (the same way a normal terminal emulator would)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> then <kbd>Esc</kbd> should get you into a special mode to look through the scroll-back buffer much like hitting <kbd>Esc</kbd> in `vim` gets you into a mode where you can navigate the file rather than inserting into it.

If your scroll-back buffer doesn't have enough lines in it to be useful you can change this in your `~/.screenrc` file:

```
defscrollback 10000
```

Once in the scroolback buffer, you can use common key bindings like <kbd>J</kbd>/<kbd>K</kbd>/<kbd>H</kbd>/<kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDown</kbd>, <kbd>G</kbd>/<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>, <kbd>^</kbd>/<kbd>$</kbd> and arrows to navigate. You can use <kbd>Space</kbd> to set a mark. Setting a second mark will copy everything between the two marks to the screen clipboard which you can then paste into any window using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>]</kbd>.

You can also search and do other things with the buffer. See the [screen users manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Copy) for more.

Comment: I am able to copy from screen buffer, but how do I paste it to gedit?

Comment: @abc: You would need to tranfer it from the screen clipboard to the X clipboard. Try using shell in screen and running: `cat - | xclip` and then `Ctrl+A ]`.

Comment: May be I am doing something wrong. cat - | xclip just hangs. I copied characters from screen buffer and then tried to paste them to a text editor and that did not work. Can you elaborate please?